# Pandas Dataframe: Extract info from specific series

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, etl, data-cleaning

I have this dataframe which need to extract package info (ML, KG, PZA, LT, UN, etc) from description column, and i'm pretty new at pandas.
This is the dataframe right now

| SKU | Description |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | TRIDENT 6S SANDIA 9GR |
| 2 | CANAST RABBIT F1 A 1UN |
| 3 | HAND SOAP VITAMIN E 442 ML. |

I need to extract 9GR, 1UN, 442 ML, etc. and take it into another column. I need to extract what matches within a list of possible values that are going to be part of the accepted Package series so this a re the possible values

[GR, UN, LT, OZ]

Anything that matches in the description column this substrings i need to replace in the column Package and remove it from description column.

Comment: What you want is to extract a string always at the end of the row?

Comment: Well, yes that could be but the question is from the end to what index. That could be one issue here for me.

Comment: What about `GR` not in your package info

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: thanks @Him. I used to try what Corralien mentioned  and it worked fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
pkg = ['ML', 'KG', 'PZA', 'LT', 'UN', 'GR']

df['package'] = df['Description'].str.extract(fr"\b(\d+\s*(?:{'|'.join(pkg)}))\b")
print(df)

# Output
   SKU                  Description package
0    1        TRIDENT 6S SANDIA 9GR     9GR
1    2       CANAST RABBIT F1 A 1UN     1UN
2    3  HAND SOAP VITAMIN E 442 ML.  442 ML
```

Comment: I added `GR` to the list of pkg

Comment: That is working fine